# get output in {{ path.url }} in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

in jekyll site I created page `categories.html` with content:

```
---
layout: default
permalink: /categories
title: Categories
---
{% assign current_cat = {{ page.url }} | split: "/" | last %}
{% assign posts = site.categories[current_cat] %}
<ul>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <li><a href="{{post.url | absolute_url}}">{{post.title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

then I want to list all post of category (only posts 1 category in page)

Example:

```
-> request: http://127.0.0.1:4000/categories/cat1
=> result: {{ path.url }} is `/categories`
=> but i want: {{ path.url }} is `/categories/cat1`
```

any idea?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a single page, and the URL is set from your front matter permalink. You could convert this page to a layout, then create pages for each category you want using that layout.

Alternatively, you could use this official plugin which does achieves the same thing: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-archives

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem occurs when my site has many categories, creating multiple page is not good action. I will consider Jekyll-archives